# How to avoid extraneous data on table joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using MSSQL 2012, I have three tables. Table 0 has a value which I use to join with some other tables like so:

```
Table0

----------
keyval
1



Table1

----------
keyval   someval
1        blah
1        blah1


Table2

----------
keyval  someotherval
1       woo
1       woo1
1       woo2
```

Now if I do the following query

```
SELECT  Table1.someval AS val1, Table2.someotherval AS val2
FROM  Table0
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table0.keyval = Table1.keyval
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table0.keyval = Table2.keyval
WHERE Table0.keyval = '1'
```

I get the following results:

```
val1    val2

----------
blah    woo
blah    woo1
blah    woo2
blah1   woo
blah1   woo1
blah1   woo2
```

My question is, how can I ensure that ***each value only displays once in the results?*** I would like to know how to run a query to get the following results

```
val1    val2

----------
blah    woo
blah1   woo1
null    woo2
```

I have tried all different kinds of joins but with no good results. I have a feeling I need UNION somewhere but I am not sure where

Comment: how is the query supposed to know that `blah` goes with `woo` and not with `woo1`? You need to add columns to make the relationships clear in the DB... since all the `keyval`'s are the same, that is the expected behaviour...

Comment: Are you just trying to join on the last character of the `val`'s?

Comment: **http://sqlfiddle.com/**

Comment: Maybe using SELECT DISTINCT ..

Comment: It seems that you want the query to figure out which of the returned columns has the most distinct values (in this case `val2`) and to then match up each value of `val2` with *any* as-yet-unused value of `val1` (that meets the join criteria), possibly using `null` if all values of `val1` have been exhausted.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT in this example will grab all 6 rows since the combination of values in each row is distinct

Comment: @serakfalcon -- basically I just want to fill a table with one of each unique value. I don`t care about the order. So whether blah goes with woo1, woo2, or woo3 it doesn`t matter. The important thing is that each column only returns each unique value once

Comment: You are still under-specifying it. What would happen if the values for `val1` were `blah`, `blah1`, `blah2`, and `blah3`?

Comment: @EMS. In that case I would just want a null value anywhere in the val2 column

Comment: Given datum don't suit the required result set. You need an extra key to match records specific to `Table1` and `Table2` relationship. Otherwise, I can't see how you can achieve the expected result. Normally, you achieve such a result set when there is data in one table with no possible correlation in the other table, hence the `null` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a random subset of the cartesian product where each value is represented once, so something like this should do:

```
with t0(k) as ( 
  select 1 
), t1(k,v1) as (
  select 1,'blah' 
  union 
  select 1,'blah1'
), t2(k,v2) as ( 
  select 1,'woo'
  union
  select 1,'woo1'
  union
  select 1,'woo2'
), t3(k,v1,rn) as ( 
  select t1.k, v1, row_number() over (order by t1.v1) as rn1 
  from t1
  join t0
      on t0.k = t1.k
), t4(k,v2,rn) as (
  select t2.k, v2, row_number() over (order by t2.v2) as rn2 
  from t2
  join t0
      on t0.k = t2.k
) 
select t3.v1, t4.v2 
from t3 
full join t4 
    on t3.k = t4.k 
   and t3.rn = t4.rn


V1      V2
blah    woo
blah1   woo1
(null)  woo2
```

Edit: using tables instead of CTE t0, t1 and t2

```
create table table0 (k int not null);
insert into table0 (k) select 1;
create table table1 (k int not null, v1 varchar(5) not null);
create table table2 (k int not null, v2 varchar(5) not null);
insert into table1 (k,v1)
select 1,'blah' 
union 
select 1,'blah1'
union
select 1, 'jojo'
union
select 1, 'jojo1';

insert into table2 (k,v2)
select 1,'woo'
union
select 1,'woo1'
union
select 1,'woo2';

with t3(k,v1,rn) as ( 
    select t1.k, v1, row_number() over (order by t1.v1) as rn1 
    from table1 t1
    join table0 t0
        on t0.k = t1.k
), t4(k,v2,rn) as (
   select t2.k, v2, row_number() over (order by t2.v2) as rn2 
   from table2 t2
   join table0 t0 
       on t0.k = t2.k
) 
select t3.v1, t4.v2 
from t3 
full join t4 
    on t3.k = t4.k
   and t3.rn = t4.rn;

V1      V2
blah    woo
blah1   woo1
jojo    woo2
jojo1   (null) 

delete from table1 where v1 like 'joj%';

with t3(k,v1,rn) as ( 
   select t1.k, v1, row_number() over (order by t1.v1) as rn1 
   from table1 t1
   join table0 t0
       on t0.k = t1.k
), t4(k,v2,rn) as (
   select t2.k, v2, row_number() over (order by t2.v2) as rn2 
   from table2 t2
   join table0 t0 
       on t0.k = t2.k
) 
select t3.v1, t4.v2 
from t3 
full join t4 
    on t3.k = t4.k 
   and t3.rn = t4.rn;

V1      V2
blah    woo
blah1   woo1
(null)  woo2
```

Comment: @Lennart: are you even pulling the data from the db?

Comment: t0, t1 and t2 simulates the tables in his query

Comment: haha no I already have this in a paramaterized stored procedure that I`m using in a web service. It works great because by putting the parameter and all the columns I need from my main table in t0, I am able to get all the relevant data without duplicating the all the data in each row. Also, the maximum amount of rows returned is equal to the greatest number of rows in one of the 'side tables'. I have a lot of these 'side tables' so this saves me a lot of data being sent over the wire.

Comment: Good just to note that the use of CTEs won't allow this to be converted to a MySQL solution if you ever have to reproduce this workflow with data in MySQL (may not be relevant, but still good to note).

Comment: @EMS, have you tried adding those values to t1? Why did it not work? Futhermore, CTE is not needed, you can solve this without them. Also, row_number() can be emulated with variables in mysql. Did you understand the solution?

Comment: You miss the point, t0, t1 and t2 does not exist, they are just emulating the OPs table0, table1 and table2. I'll update the solution and then you can point out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it will be a lot easier to pull the unique values into a single column,
and then use a second 'dummy' column to specify where the values came from.
Since they don't necessarily match up with eachother, there's no reason to list them out in pairs.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Table1.someval AS val,'Table1' As source
 FROM Table1
 WHERE Table1.keyval = '1'
 UNION
 SELECT DISTINCT Table2.someval as val, 'Table2' As source
 FROM Table2
 WHERE Table2.keyval = '1'
```

Note, in this case, I dropped `Table0` entirely, with the data set up the way it is in your  question, the only time `Table0` will matter is if there is no keyval = 1 in `Table0`, in which case you will get no results.

But, if that matters to you,

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Table1.someval AS val,'Table1' As source
 FROM Table1
 INNER JOIN Table0 ON Table0.keyval = Table1.keyval
 WHERE Table0.keyval = '1'
 UNION
 SELECT DISTINCT Table2.someval as val, 'Table2' As source
 FROM Table2
 INNER JOIN Table0 ON Table0.keyval = Table2.keyval
 WHERE Table0.keyval = '1'
```

Comment: Yeah, I`ve been thinking this is probably the best way to do it as well. I`m going to wait a bit to see if any sql ninjas have some sneaky solution here; otherwise I`ll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

The closer I get based on given datum is:

```
select s.val1, s.val2
    from (
        select t1.someval as val1
                , null as val2
            from table1 t1
        union
        select null as val1
                , t2.someotherval as val2
            from table2 t2
    ) s
```

Which result is:

```
val1  | val2
--------------
blah  | (null)
blah1 | (null)
(null)| woo
(null)| woo1
(null)| woo2
```

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9482c/6).

Otherwise, you can achieve this:

```
  val
-------
 blah
 blah1
 woo
 woo1
 woo2
```

With this query:

```
select t1.someval as val
    from table1 t1
union
    select t2.someotherval 
        from table2 t2
```

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9482c/9).

Though neither is the desired result set, this is the closest I can get with the given input.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to see NULL results from a joined table, use 'LEFT JOIN'.

```
SELECT  Table1.someval AS val1, Table2.someotherval AS val2
FROM  Table0
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table0.keyval = Table1.keyval
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table0.keyval = Table2.keyval
WHERE Table0.keyval = '1'
```

Comment: Where do you expect to find NULL values? Table0, Table1, or Table2?

Comment: Looking at the data in the tables you provided, there will be no NULL values because each of the keys will find a match (Table0.keyval, Table1.keyval, Table2.keyval).